# CSV lines in array(), need to preserve line breaks

Tags: php, csv, newline, fputcsv

I have an array in the following format - it's essentially an array of preformatted CSV lines - key 0 and 1 in this example have a CSV value containing a line break.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'foo,foo,foo,foo
    bar,foo,a:1:{i:0;s:4:"blah";}'
    [1] => 'bar,bar,bar,bar
    foo,bar,a:1:{i:0;s:4:"blah";}'
    [1] => 'bar,bar,bar,foo,bar,a:1:{i:0;s:4:"blah";}'
)
```

What I am doing next, is imploding that using `\r\n` as the glue, to generate the CSV file, then writing it out. The problem is that the resultant file does not wrap the fields containing a line break in double quotes so that the line break may be preserved (or at least I am assuming it will).

The CSV file generated will be uploaded to a database or edited in Excel and the line breaks need to be preserved in the field.

Using fputcsv after exploding into the right format generates a CSV which has the line break and wrapped in a double quote viewed in Notepad or similar but not when opened in Excel.

```
  $parent_wholelines = array();
  foreach ($output_array as $wholeline) {
    $parent_wholelines[] = explode(',', $wholeline);
  }
```

Comment: Prefer `var_export`. `print_r` isn't very good at showing us _precisely_ what your data is.

Comment: @Tomalak-Geret'kal - var_export outputs the same thing in this case, plus some per key wrapping quotes.

Comment: Yes; those are useful. Precision is important in our field.

Answer (score -1):

One snippet from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php, maybe could help you.
OR get a use of serialize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: Thanks, but that's just a copy and paste from php.net's fputcsv. I know how to use it, I am asking a different question because my data is not in that format. I am aware of serialize() because that's how some of the sample data is created. I can't use it to store the entire string because I am not authoring the final import of the CSV, I just need to write it.